# What does putting code in a curly brace block mean

Tags: java, php

IN php, and some other languages i can have a code block without any entry conditions such as if, or for or function call:

```
   echo "Hello World";

   {
    echo "What does this mean";

   }
```

What does this signify exactly. If I am not wrong, I can also do this in java. What exactly does this signify?

Answer (score 5):

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_%28programming%29) - Blocks create what is somewhat an atomic unit of code.  In the top/entering level flow of execution a block is treated as what amounts to one line.

Answer (score -1):

It defines the scope. ie the variables defined inside the block will not be available out side of the block.

Comment: Nope: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d95e3b0bbb739afceb57d2be4c8398db7c291a93

Comment: @John What is this suppose to prove? You defined $test outside the code block where "test" is assigned to replace "hi".

Comment: @JP That Biju is not right with his answer. $test it should echo "hi" if Biju was right.

Comment: I dont know PHP. I was telling a general concept regarding the code blocks using '{'. it is true for C#.